# grub-install error Failed to register the EFI boot entry: Interrupted system call

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am installing Linux Mint Mate 20.2 as dual-boot with Windows 10. It all goes fine until it gets to grub-install. There it throws a Fatal Error, with the command line in the installer saying:

Failed to register the EFI boot entry: Interrupted system call

I am using three partitions for Mint:
Ext4 mounted as: "/"
Ext4 mounted as: "/home"
and a swap-area
Windows has 4 partitions:
NTFS: "C:"
EFI
Recovery
Partition 2 (weighs ~16Mb, doesn't show up in Windows Partition tool)
How do I fix this?
Note:
Fast Startup, Hibernation are disabled
Secure boot is disabled
Edit (grub install logs):

```
debconf (developer): --> 1 Installing the 'grub2' package...
Jan  5 08:50:31 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO grub-installer/progress/step_os-probe
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/progress/step_os-probe description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Looking for other operating systems...
Jan  5 08:50:47 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- SETTITLE debian-installer/grub-installer/title
debconf (developer): <-- SETTITLE debian-installer/grub-installer/title
debconf (developer): --> 0
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- SUBST grub-installer/with_other_os OS_LIST
debconf (developer): <-- SUBST grub-installer/with_other_os OS_LIST
debconf (developer): --> 0
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- GET grub-installer/bootdev
debconf (developer): <-- GET grub-installer/bootdev
debconf (developer): --> 1 /dev/mmcblk1
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- GET cdrom-detect/hybrid
debconf (developer): <-- GET cdrom-detect/hybrid
debconf (developer): --> 10 cdrom-detect/hybrid doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO grub-installer/progress/step_bootdev
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/progress/step_bootdev description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Determining GRUB boot device...
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- FGET grub-installer/bootdev seen
debconf (developer): <-- FGET grub-installer/bootdev seen
debconf (developer): --> 0 true
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- GET grub-installer/bootdev
debconf (developer): <-- GET grub-installer/bootdev
debconf (developer): --> 1 /dev/mmcblk1
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- SUBST grub-installer/progress/step_install_loader BOOTDEV /dev/mmcblk1
debconf (developer): <-- SUBST grub-installer/progress/step_install_loader BOOTDEV /dev/mmcblk1
debconf (developer): --> 0
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO grub-installer/progress/step_install_loader
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/progress/step_install_loader description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Running "grub-install /dev/mmcblk1"...
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- INPUT low grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable Type
debconf (developer): --> 1 boolean
debconf (developer): <-- INPUT low grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable
debconf (developer): --> 30 question skipped
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- GO 
debconf (developer): <-- GO 
debconf (developer): --> 0 ok
Jan  5 08:50:50 debconf (filter): <-- GET grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable
debconf (developer): <-- GET grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable
debconf (developer): --> 1 false
Jan  5 08:50:51 debconf (filter): <-- SUBST grub-installer/grub-install-failed BOOTDEV /dev/mmcblk1
debconf (developer): <-- SUBST grub-installer/grub-install-failed BOOTDEV /dev/mmcblk1
debconf (developer): --> 0
Jan  5 08:50:51 debconf (filter): <-- INPUT critical grub-installer/grub-install-failed
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/grub-install-failed Type
debconf (developer): --> 1 error
Jan  5 08:50:51 debconf (filter): error widget found for grub-installer/grub-install-failed
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/grub-install-failed description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Unable to install GRUB in /dev/mmcblk1
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET grub-installer/grub-install-failed extended_description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Executing 'grub-install /dev/mmcblk1' failed.\n\nThis is a fatal error.
Jan  5 08:51:02 ubiquity: Partman: Thawing choices for choose_partition
Jan  5 08:51:02 ubiquity: Partman: Thawing choices for active_partition
debconf (developer): <-- GET ubiquity/install_bootloader
debconf (developer): --> 1 true
Jan  5 08:51:02 ubiquity: Starting up '['log-output', '-t', 'ubiquity', '--pass-stdout', 'sh', '-c', '/usr/share/ubiquity/activate-dmraid && /bin/partman']' for ubi-partman.Page
Jan  5 08:51:02 ubiquity: Watching for question patterns ^partman-auto/.*automatically_partition$, ^partman-auto/select_disk$, ^partman-partitioning/confirm_resize$, ^partman-partitioning/confirm_new_label$, ^partman-partitioning/new_size$, ^partman/choose_partition$, ^partman/confirm.*, ^partman/free_space$, ^partman/active_partition$, ^partman-crypto/passphrase.*, ^partman-crypto/weak_passphrase$, ^partman-crypto/confirm.*, ^partman-crypto/mainmenu$, ^partman-lvm/confirm.*, ^partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm, ^partman-partitioning/new_partition_(size|type|place)$, ^partman-target/choose_method$, ^partman-basicfilesystems/(fat_mountpoint|mountpoint|mountpoint_manual)$, ^partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap$, ^partman-uboot/mountpoint$, ^partman/exception_handler$, ^partman/exception_handler_note$, ^partman/unmount_active$, ^partman/installation_medium_mounted$, type:boolean, ERROR, PROGRESS
debconf (developer): <-- CAPB escape
debconf (developer): --> 0 multiselect escape 
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- CAPB backup align
debconf (developer): <-- CAPB backup align escape
debconf (developer): --> 0 multiselect escape 
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- CAPB backup align
debconf (developer): <-- CAPB backup align escape
debconf (developer): --> 0 multiselect escape 
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 question will be asked
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- GO 
debconf (developer): <-- GO 
debconf (developer): --> 0 ok
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STOP
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for grub-installer/progress/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS START 0 20 partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/title Type
debconf (developer): --> 1 text
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/title description
debconf (developer): --> 1 Starting up the partitioner
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/early_command
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/early_command description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/early_command doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- GET apt-setup/disable-cdrom-entries
debconf (developer): <-- GET apt-setup/disable-cdrom-entries
debconf (developer): --> 1 false
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- GET partman/early_command
debconf (developer): <-- GET partman/early_command
debconf (developer): --> 1 
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/unsupported
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/unsupported description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/unsupported doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_basicfilesystems
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_basicfilesystems description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_basicfilesystems doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_btrfs
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_btrfs description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_btrfs doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_ext3
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_ext3 description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_ext3 doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_jfs
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_jfs description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_jfs doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_xfs
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_xfs description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/kernelmodules_xfs doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STEP 1
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS INFO partman/progress/init/umount_target
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
debconf (developer): <-- METAGET partman/progress/init/umount_target description
debconf (developer): --> 10 partman/progress/init/umount_target doesn't exist
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): <-- PROGRESS STOP
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): widget found for partman/progress/init/title
Jan  5 08:51:02 debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
Jan  5 08:51:02 ubiquity: ['log-output', '-t', 'ubiquity', '--pass-stdout', 'sh', '-c', '/usr/share/ubiquity/activate-dmraid && /bin/partman'] exited with code 10
```

As requested here is the Boot Repair pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d2JMGYFGgR/

Comment: is Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @Alex It is, but the problem persists

Comment: Please post logs from the installation, when it gets to that stage. You can launch the installer via terminal with `ubiquity`  or look into the details box during the GUI install.

Comment: How would I run the install with ```ubiquity```? I ran the command ```ubiquity``` and it opened the GUI install

Comment: yes this is the point. During the install, there should be things logged inside the terminal, from which you opened ubiquity. The second option I mentioned earlier is also considerable. Get to the point where grub fails to install and add the logs into your original post

Comment: When the install fails, I no longer have access to GUI box, and ```ubiquity``` doesn't output anything into the original terminal, only the GUI terminal. I have however noticed that during grub2 installation it wasn't able to detect either the volume, disk or partition.

Comment: @Alex I have added the relevant (or so I think) logs

Comment: Is there a raid somewhere involved in your current setup?

Comment: No. When I am installing Mint, I have no other disks plugged in and the partitions I listed are the only ones that exist on the built in SSD in my laptop.

Comment: Ignore the 16MB partition. It is a Windows System Reserved and must be unformatted. But then unformatted partitions are shown as errors in Linux. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1032905 my guess is that this is occurring.

Comment: @oldfred where do I find Bootinfo summary report? What auto fix? I used Rufus to create the boot drive

Comment: @Alex so I need to create an EFI partition, (according to a tutorial, 512MB), a root, a home and a swap area. So 4 partitions total for Mint?

Comment: @HighElfWisard swap and a separate /home are not necessary, they are only a recommendation

Comment: swap is kinda important with 4GB ram

Comment: @Alex I tried with 200MB EFI 4096MB swap ~46GB root, it failed

Comment: @HighElfWisard please try booting the installer with `nodmraid` option. When the live cd/usb boots and you select the install options, press F6 and select the `nodmraid` option. Try to install it with this option enabled

Comment: @Alex When I select what to do on boot of the live usb (Start Mint, Start Mint compatibility, OEM Install, check the integrity) F6 doesn't do anything at this stage

Comment: Found a workaround: Install without GRUB, reinstall GRUB with Boot Repair